# Integral weighted graphs

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I found some useful guidelines to investigate integral graphs (i.e. that the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix are all integers) http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0066434 .

However, something that can be said about weighted graphs I couldn't be able to find. I am interested in weighted graphs whose adjacency matrix has in all it's entries positive numbers $\ge 0$.

Comment: Do you have a question? I saw no question, or question marks for that matter.

Comment: What are the eigenvalue/eigenvector properties of such matrices, for instance. Can you construct integral weighted matrices similar of what you can do with integral graphs?